# How can I check free space during a NullSoft silent install?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, diskspace

In silent install mode the user is not asked about the installation target with the [`PageEx directory`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.5.6), and therefore the functions [`DirVerify`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.16) and [`GetInstDirError`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.7.2) are never called.

This is also applicable to installs that hardcode the installation target (a bad idea) for the same reason as above: the `PageEx directory` is never invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code is ok, but calling ${DriveSpace} on Win9x could fail. I also removed the need to specify the section id's

```
!define APPNAME "CalcEnoughSpace"
name "${APPNAME}"
outfile "$%temp%\${APPNAME}.exe"
ShowInstDetails show
RequestExecutionLevel user
installdir "$Temp"
AllowRootDirInstall true

!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
push $instdir
call VerifyFreeSpace
pop $0
${If} $0 < 1
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Not enough free space!"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

page instfiles

Section !a
AddSize 10000
SectionEnd
Section /o b
AddSize 10000
SectionEnd

SectionGroup grp
Section c
AddSize 10000
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd



Function VerifyFreeSpace
System::Store s
pop $0 ;path to check
Push 0 ;default to no
System::Call 'kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(tr0,*l.r1,*l,*l)i.r2'
${If} $2 < 1 
    StrCpy $0 $0 3
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpace(tr0,*i.r1,*i.r2,*i.r3,*i)i.r4'
    IntCmpU $4 0 ret 
    IntOp $1 $1 * $2
    System::Int64Op $1 * $3
    pop $1  
${EndIf}
System::Int64Op $1 / 1024 ;to kb
pop $1
StrCpy $4 0 ;size
StrCpy $2 0 ;section idx
loop:
    ClearErrors
    SectionGetFlags $2 $3
    IfErrors testspace
    IntOp $3 $3 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    ${If} $3 <> 0
        SectionGetSize $2 $3
        IntOp $4 $4 + $3
        ${EndIf}
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    goto loop
testspace:
pop $2 ;throw away default return value
System::Int64Op $1 > $4
ret:
System::Store l
FunctionEnd
```

I only did limited testing, hopefully there are no bugs :)

Comment: Thanks @Anders, I'll try this. I never write anything for Win95, but better to be prepared...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function called `CheckFreeSpace` in NSIS to do this. Unfortunately it has the following limitations:

- To compute the size of all the sections in your installation, you have to modify `CheckFreeSpace` to add each section, by knowing each variable that each section id was written into. I can't find a way of iterating over all sections that will be installed using NSIS.
- Installation drive must be computed because `${DriveSpace}` requires a drive letter, not a path to an arbitrary directory. The drive letter string is computed with `StrCpy $instdrive $INSTDIR 3`. If the `$INSTDIR` variable is a relative path or does not begin with a string such as `C:\`, this will fail.
- If the installation cannot continue it produces a `MessageBox`. You can suppress the `MessageBox` by adding `/SD IDOK` at the end of the statement, but then the user is not informed of the installation failure: I can't find a way to emit to `stdout` from NSIS. Perhaps the return code from the installer is enough?
- If the disk free space is really low (like 10kb), the installer won't run at all; it doesn't have space to unpack its temporary DLL's into the `\tmp` directory.

Also, in my implementation below, `CheckFreeSpace` has a hardcoded value for the space free after installation. Obviously that can be parameterized.

Here it is within a sample installer:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!insertmacro DriveSpace

Name "CheckFreeSpace"
OutFile "C:\CheckFreeSpace.exe"

InstallDir C:\tmp\checkfreespace

Page instfiles

Section "install_section" install_section_id
    Call CheckFreeSpace

    CreateDirectory $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File "C:\installme.bat"

    WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

    DetailPrint "Installation Successful."
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"

    RMDIR /r "$INSTDIR"

SectionEnd

Function CheckFreeSpace

    var /GLOBAL installsize
    var /GLOBAL adjustedinstallsize
    var /GLOBAL freespace
    var /GLOBAL instdrive

    ; Verify that we have sufficient space for the install

    ; SectionGetSize returns the size of each section in kilobyte.
    SectionGetSize ${install_section_id} $installsize

    ; Adjust the required install size by 10mb, as a minimum amount
    ; of free space left after installation.
    IntOp $adjustedinstallsize $installsize + 10240

    ; Compute the drive that is the installation target; the
    ; ${DriveSpace} macro will not accept a path, it must be a drive.
    StrCpy $instdrive $INSTDIR 3

    ; Compute drive space free in kilobyte
    ${DriveSpace} $instdrive "/D=F /S=K" $freespace

    DetailPrint "Determined installer needs $adjustedinstallsize kb ($installsize kb) while $freespace kb is free"

    IntCmp $adjustedinstallsize $freespace spaceok spaceok

    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "Insufficient space for installation. Please free space for installation directory $INSTDIR and try again."
    DetailPrint "Insufficient space for installation. Installer needs $adjustedinstallsize kb, but freespace is only $freespace kb."
    Abort "Insufficient space for installation."

  spaceok:
    DetailPrint "Installation target space is sufficient"

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: If the assumptions in my question or answer are wrong, please correct them. At this time, this code seems to work with low free space conditions.

Comment: the section id is just a number starting from 0, so you could just make a loop to check all sections, call SectionGetFlags to see if the section is selected/checked, if it is, call SectionGetSize, if the error flag is set after calling SectionGetFlags, you have reached the end

Comment: As far as output to stdout goes, NSIS is a GUI app so there is not really any console handling. On XP and later its possible if you use the system plugin, see http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?postid=2303779#post2303779

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample script for silent install?